# build php-style URLs with arrays - with Python

Tags: php, python, url

An array is encoded in a URL by PHP uses [] notation, e.g.

```
$f = array( 'a', 'b', 'c');
http_build_query( array('f'=> $f) );
http://server/q.php?f[]=aaaa&f[]=bbb&f[]=ccc
```

In Python I haven't seen such notation. Instead, I usually saw:

```
f = [ 'a', 'b', 'c']
http://server/q.py?f=aaaa&f=bbb&f=ccc
```

Is there a ready-made method IN PYTHON to encode arrays for PHP to chew on ?

**EDIT**

Addressing specific comments i've seen: The following lines do NOT get interpreted the same way in PHP.  Run it with phpinfo() if you don't believe me, @Daniel:

```
test.php?f=1&f=zzzzz&f=b
test.php?f[]=1&f[]=zzzzz&f[]=b
```

And to that guy that renamed "f" as "f[]" through a loop: thank you, but i was asking for  a built-in solution or a module.

It is important for me not to reinvent wheels, especially for cases where the query is very complicated, with mixed data types, e.g. { 'str': 'asd123#$', 'arr': [ 'val%', ')(*^&$@$', 'val3', 123.21], 'd': { 'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}. I happen to use larger and more complicated cases for an API that requires them as URLs.

**EDIT 2**

i wonder why this question is down-voted:

this is a legitimate question about bridging python code and a PHP website through the URL.

in my case: HasOffers.com has API that accepts GET requests in PHP fashion.

Also, as mentioned before, url encoding tend to get complicated.

Comment: `$_GET['f']` should pick `f` up as an array nonetheless

Comment: as a side note, in python they're called `list`s.

Comment: I don't think there's a ready made built-in in Python to support PHP's queries, if that's what you wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
>>> a = 'a b c'.split()
>>> a
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> def help_build_query(l):
...     return "http://server/q.py?{}=aaaa&{}=bbb&{}=ccc".format(*l)
...
>>> help_build_query(a)
'http://server/q.py?a=aaaa&b=bbb&c=ccc'
>>>
```

`a` is a list that has been split. The `{}` is used as place holders. The `*` is called a splat operator, and it makes each of the variables in the list, an argument to a function.

Comment: the desired result is  'http://server/q.py?a[]=aaaa&a[]=bbb&a[]=ccc'.  It's the same "a" variable.